# Magento 2.3.2 Category API returns null attributes for the entire tree

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.3.2

When I am trying to call the REST API for generating the Category tree, it shows null values for the entire attribute except id and parent_id

URL: rest/all/V1/categories
Version: Magento Commerce 2.3.2

This is a fresh installation on local environment and there are no third party modules or theme installed.

Please see the screenshot for the out of API

[image]

Comment: have you tried re:indexing?

Comment: yes, but no change. This is a Magento 2.3.2 bug

Comment: Any reference or solution to the bug? what you did?

Comment: The issue was in file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Tree.php
Magento have released a patch for this.